# Approve Purchase Orders in eConnect?

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

I am looking for the capability to approve a Purchase Order in Dynamics GP using eConnect. I do not see this capability when reviewing the eConnect Programmer's Guide, but I would like someone with more experience to verify that I am not missing it, please.

If it matters, please realize I also have no experience in approving POs through the GP application so I am not certain how this operates on its own. I have a vague recollection that this approval happens in a workflow whose functionality was added somewhat recently in GP's history. So perhaps a second question, is this approval functionality part of the stock Dynamics GP install or no?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add purchase order approval functionality to Dynamics GP by enabling the option in the Purchase Order Enhancements Setup window.

Microsoft Dynamics GP menu -> Tools -> Setup -> Purchasing -> Purchase Order Enhancements

Refer to the manual for Purchase Order Enhancements from your installation media or download it directly from Microsoft.

In a nutshell, it allows you to set up security around approvals with limits on dollar amounts and restrictions by purchase order number, vendor, or created by.

There is no eConnect integration to approve purchase orders, but you may create your own process by extending eConnect with custom SQL logic. If you are unfamiliar with the database schema in Dynamics GP you may want to reach out to a Dynamics GP Partner for assistance with that development. I wouldn't recommend directly modifying data in the Dynamics GP database without a complete understanding of the impact.

With that said, this is a fairly simple customization for someone with a good understanding and experience with the purchase order module in Dynamics GP.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Microsoft Dynamics GP menu -> Tools -> Setup -> Purchasing -> Purchase Order Enhancements and activate the approval setup.
Once the user having PURCHASING role he can able to approve any PO.